# Problema com seleção no MySql

Tags: java, mysql

Galera estou iniciando neste negócio e tendo dificuldade na seleção em mais de uma tabela.

Meu comando de seleção foi o seguinte:

**Tabela 01:**

```
select * from veiculo;
```

```
|id_veiculo|modelo|cor|placa|chassi|renavam|combustivel|ano|hp|id_proprietario|id_uf|id_fabricante| 

|101001|Logan|Preta|JHE-3814|1234BFBF12|DF1234BR1234|GASOL/ALCOOL|2012|77|100|1|1010|
|101002|Corolla|Prata|JHJ-0007|2222BFBF22|DF4321BR4321|GASOLINA|2007|107|101|2|1011|
|101003|Strada|Vermelha|JHA-1221|3333BFBF11|MG0202BR4321|ALCOOL|2015|132|102|3|1012|
```

**Tabela 02:**

```
select * from fabricante;
```

```
|id_fabricante|nome|presidente|observacoes

|1010|Pedro Motta|RENAULT|Presidente da Renault em São Paulo e Rio de Janeiro|
|1011|Silvia Santos|TOYOTA|Presidente da Toyota em Brasília, Porto Alegre e Campo Grande|
|1012|Fausto Silva|FIAT|Presidente da Fiat no Brasil
```

**Este SQL está dando erro:**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM veiculo t1, fabricante t2 
WHERE t1.id_fabricante= t2.id_fabricante AND t1.veiculo 
LIKE  "JHJ%" AND t1.ano <> 2000 AND t1.combustivel="GASOLINA" AND t2.presidente="TOYOTA";
```

**ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't1.veiculo' in 'where clause'**

Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é bem claro: a tabela `veiculo` não tem a coluna `veiculo`. Pelo visto, você queria procurar por `t1.placa` ao invés de `t1.veiculo`. A consulta correta seria:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*FROM veiculo t1, fabricante t2 
WHERE t1.id_fabricante = t2.id_fabricante AND t1.placa LIKE "JHJ%" 
AND t1.ano <> 2000 AND t1.combustivel = "GASOLINA" AND t2.presidente = "TOYOTA";
```

Comment: caracas, estou a horas tentando achar o erro.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: @DaviNascimento que bom que foi resolvido... pode marcar a resposta como correta? :)

Comment: Ainda não consig